# Sporadic TemplateDoesNotExist errors in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a django (v1.1.1) on a server running Python 2.4. On my localhost/development computer the site works perfect. When I uploaded the files to the production server, it seemed to work fine, but after a page refresh I am receiving random TemplateDoesNotExist errors.

In the trace report I looked at the TEMPLATE_DIRS variable to make sure I was pointing to the right place, and it actually changes each time I refresh the page between this:

TEMPLATE_DIRS
('templates', '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/apps')

and this

TEMPLATE_DIRS
('templates', '/var/www/django-sites/apps/templates')

How is it possible that django/python is looking in two different locations when I refresh the page? After 3-4 attempts it suddenly works until I either refresh or go to the next page. The correct location is /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/apps/templates which is definted in my settings.py file:

```
# Django settings for django-sites project.

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'
DATABASE_NAME = 'mysite'
DATABASE_USER = 'mysuser'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
DATABASE_HOST = 'www.mysite.com'            
DATABASE_PORT = ''  


# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'mysecretkey'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'apps.urls'
URL_ROOT_LEAD_CAPTURE = '/lead-capture/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
)

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
    '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/apps/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you uploaded the .pyc executed on the local machine, they should be overwritten when you restart the app though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with your apache configuration or what ever you are using for the web server.  The PROJECT_ROOT:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Is dependent upon the current absolute path which is set by what ever environment is running the application.  Make sure that only one route for handling URLs exists in your web server configuration.

Second,  make sure all django environments have been cleanly shutdown, you may have some old, misconfigured environments around serving requests.